# How many repaints of the DOM will appending children in a for loop cause?

Tags: javascript, dom

**How many repaints of the DOM will appending children in a for loop cause?**

I was under the impression this would cause 200. 1 for each time an element is appended, and 1 every time its textContent is updated.

But, in [Jake Archibald's talk at JSConf](https://youtu.be/cCOL7MC4Pl0?t=1494), he seems to mention that browsers will batch this together.

```
for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++){ 
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  document.body.appendChild(div);
  div.textContent = 'Hello';
}
```

Comment: JavaScript and rendering share one queue/thread, so rendering can't happen while JS runs.

Comment: The profiler in your developer tools will show you how often each of the mentioned events happens

Comment: @Andreas - surprisingly noob question here, but how can you start the Chrome profiler then go to the console to run a script? I can't seem to find anything on this - clicking profiler stops navigation between dev tabs.

Answer (score 1):

Only once; see Erin Zimmer's continuation on the rendering pipeline https://youtu.be/u1kqx6AenYw

Also, you may test it with something like:

````
//document.body.innerHTML = '';
for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++){ 
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  document.body.appendChild(div);
  div.textContent = 'Hello';
  let x = 0;
  for(let j = 0; j < 1e7; j++){
     x += Math.sin(Math.random())
  }
}```
````